# Struct address to use in DLL

Tags: c++, struct, lua

I've got the address of struct(I think it is good one) 0040336C
I tried to use it in the DLL I am injecting into some program(where the address is)

It's really experimental because I am trying to get lua_State address.

```
data:0040336C ?L@@3PAUlua_State@@A dd ?               ; DATA XREF: _main+Cw

lua_State* L = (lua_State*)0x0040336C;
```

I tried this way but program crashes just after I inject it.

(What debugger says)

> Unhandled exception at 0x003a19e8 in
>   midaslua.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location
>   0x443de713.

Comment: I'm interested to know *why* you want to do this. Can you explain more background?

Comment: Like I said it's experimental. I am trying to build in LUA module straight into exe. With this second task I have no problem. I can use require but it's not what I want in this case.

Comment: Ok, so you want to inject something into a exe that can run a script? Hmmmm ...

Comment: More or less. But yes and I know it's possible.
http://www.ownedcore.com/forums/world-of-warcraft/world-of-warcraft-bots-programs/wow-memory-editing/196981-call-lua-function-get-result.html

Answer (score 0):

The first address you cited is an address of struct *inside a DLL's data section*, but the address you are trying to dereference is an address *in the process's memory*. These two addresses are *not* of the same kind, so it is impossible to use them like you did.

Effectively, you tried to dereference a piece of memory, where application might or might not have stored some data and treated this piece of memory as a `lua_State` (which, mostly probably, it is not). That resulted in undefined behavior, ending up with an AV.

It's hard (maybe even impossible) to locate a place in memory, where this variable is stored in process's memory. Another approach is advised.

Comment: I am injecting this DLL to this process as I mentioned above.
It works if I am using e.g. *(int*)0x4206620. It's not hard to locate a place when you're using IDA.

Comment: I guess, that you wanted to write (int \*)0x4206620. It may or may not work, depending on if application owns this place of memory or not. If so, you'll retreive four consecutive bytes stored at that place (mostly probably not being a lua_State at all). These are two different *kinds* of addresses, it simply won't work that way.

Comment: @user1857483: If that "works", you must be using WinXP or something. On a decent OS, like any semi-recent OS, that address would be different *every time* the executable is run.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization#Microsoft_Windows

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_memory_allocation You're trying to show me dynamic addresses. I know this science shit.